# How to run javascript/javascript in a XLST file

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xslt

Im attempting to run some javascript/jquery in a XSLT file to move a div, but its not taking effect, im wondering what I am doing wrong? Any help would be much appreciated!

```
<lxslt:script lang="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".outter").appendTo(".inner");
});
</lxslt:script>
```

Heres the whole file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" ></xsl:output>
<xsl:template match="/">
<style type="text/css">
  .outter { margin: 0 0 14px 0 }      
</style>

<div class="outter">
  <xsl:attribute name="lang">
    <xsl:value-of select="//Labels/Language"></xsl:value-of>
  </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="dir">
    <xsl:value-of select="//Labels/TextDirection"></xsl:value-of>
  </xsl:attribute>


  <p class="dialogText">
    <xsl:value-of select="//Labels/Title" ></xsl:value-of>. <xsl:value-of select="//Labels/Text" ></xsl:value-of>
  </p>


</div>

    <lxslt:script lang="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".CookieDeclaration").appendTo(".mcontent");
});
</lxslt:script>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Where did you get the idea that an element `lxslt:script` has any meaning? Which meaning do you think it has? Which tool should interpret that element, the XSLT processor? Which one? If you want the browser that renders the result of the XSLT transformation to execute some script in the result then use a normal HTML `script` element, like you use a normal HTML `div` or `p` element.

Comment: And if that's the entire stylesheet then it's not valid because the lxslt namespace prefix isn't bound to any URI: if it were bound to a URI we might be able make some guesses about what's going on. Any calls out from XSLT to other languages are very dependent on the XSLT processor you are using, which you haven't told us.